# Object doesn’t support property or method ‘readAsBinaryString’ - Internet Explorer 11

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, internet-explorer

Salesforce Lightning component won't attach my files in internet explorer 11, I have searched for a few solutions but none have worked, any ideas.

My code for attaching the file is as follows.

```
doAttach : function(component, event, helper) {
    var elem = event.target || event.srcElement; 
    var fileInput = $("#file-upload");

    if(fileInput[0].files.length <= 0){
        alert('You have to select a file to upload!');
        return;
    }

    var file = fileInput[0].files[0];
    if(file.size > 4500000){ // 6000000 * 3/4 to account for base64 
        alert('File size cannot exceed ' + this.MAX_FILE_SIZE + ' bytes.\n' +
                'Selected file size: ' + file.size);
        return;
    }

    //display panel loading
    $('#loading-status').css("display", "block");
    $(elem).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    var filename = file.name;
    var filesize = file.size;
    var fileblob;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(readerEvt){
        var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
        fileblob = btoa(binaryString);

        var obj = {"filename" : filename,
                   "filesize" : filesize,
                   "body" : fileblob};
        var lstresult = component.get("v.lstAttachments"); 
        lstresult.push(obj);
        component.set("v.lstAttachments", lstresult); 

        $("#elem-upload").css("display", "inline-flex");
        $("#itemUploaded").css("display", "none");  
        $("#tbl-result").css("display", "table");
        $('#loading-status').css("display", "none");
        $("#btn-attach").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
},
```

Comment: Where are you using this component? Lightning communities, an app?

Comment: I think there are some limitations as to ie11 support for lightning

Comment: Yeah its being using in a community

Comment: did you check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391207/javascript-readasbinarystring-function-on-e11

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString this link states method has no support for IE11

Comment: I haven't tried that one tried a couple others. I'll implement that when I get home

Comment: No joy I am afraid :(